# Update row with Loopback.js in Android

Tags: android, node.js, loopbackjs

I create a restful api with loopback(Node.js) for my Android app.
I can use `findById`, `destroy` etc. But when I try to update my data just work for `first_name`.
How can I solve this problem?

My Codes :
**MainActivity**

```
 public void guncelle(View view) {
    repository.findById(user_id.getText(), new ModelRepository.FindCallback<Users>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Users user) {
            if (user == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hata oluştu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
              user.put("first_name", first_name.getText()); //This is work
              user.put("last_name", last_name.getText()); // nope
          user.put("email", email.getText()); //nope
               user.put("username", username.getText()); // and nope :(

                user.save(new VoidCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Güncelleme Başarılı", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hata oluştu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("Hata: ", String.valueOf(t));
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hata oluştu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("Hata: ", String.valueOf(t));
        }

    });
}
```

**Users**

```
public class Users extends Model {

private String first_name, last_name, email, username;

public void setFirst_Name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getFirst_Name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I'm using old codes in github but new ones are work.

```
        Users user= repository.createObject(ImmutableMap.of("id", 2));
    user.setFirst_name("Name");
    user.setLast_name("Surname");
    user.setEmail("Email");
    user.setUsername("Username");
    user.save(new VoidCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Pencil now exists on the server!
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable t) {
            // save failed, handle the error
        }
    });
```